# Cannot open Miktex: Invalid or unsupported charset:utf-8.utf-8

Tags: miktex, unicode, linux

I've been using miktex for months without "unsolvable" problems. However, now, unexpectedly,  when I open the MiKTeX Console it appears the following error message:

**Invalid or unsupported charset:utf-8.utf-8**

and the console does not open. Furthermore, I cannot compile any latex file. When I use texify, or compile with the editor it appears the following error message:

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::locale::conv::invalid_charset_error'**

I use an Ubuntu 20.04.3, recently updated. However, I remember that I had compiled a file after the update so it may not be the problem.

Checking errors in the .log files inside .miktex directory I've finded

**INFO  initexmf.core - forking...**

**ERROR initexmf.core - Something is wrong with the PATH:**

**ERROR initexmf.core - /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sb>**

So may be there's a wrong path set in some file.
**How can I know which is the corrupted file?**

Thank you for any ideas or comments about this. I'm sorry that I cannot provide more information, these error messages seem to be very cryptic.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, I have no idea what you mean by "open miktex", but beside this the miktex issue tracker is here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: I mean when opening the MiKTeX Console. Thanks I will check the problem in the tracker.

Comment: Is your locale (i.e., in "Settings->Language and Region") correctly set? You can check what the command `locale` gives you.

Comment: I suppose yes

LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: ...seems ok... (you have a similar mix than I have). No further ideas, sorry...